# Swift setToolbarHidden doesn't work

Tags: swift

am working on the Udacity's Memeapp project and trying to hide the nav and toolbar before the screenshot is taken. However, the setToolbarHidden doesn't seem to work. The screenshot still has the toolbar. My code as such:

```
func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let memedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)

    return memedImage
}
```

Any help here is much appreciated pls, thanks!

EDITS:

Both my nav bar and toolbar are added in Storyboard.

[Pls see screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk7Ba.png)

[And, the nav panel here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCE4p.png)

Comment: Try to hide `toolbar` and `navigationBar` without animatation, means set animated to `false` first two lines.

Comment: @NiravD I have tried, it gives me the same results.

Comment: Please don't include the answer in your question. If an answer solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted; you can also post your own answer if you resolved your problem yourself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
toolBar.isHidden = newValue
tabBar.isHidden = newValue
```

This sample will create screen shot and will display it.

### Full sample

> Extensions.swift

```
extension UIApplication {

    var screenShot: UIImage?  {

        let layer = keyWindow!.layer
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return screenshot
    }
}
```

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!

    private var _barsAreHidden = false
    var barsAreHidden:Bool {
        set (newValue) {
            //navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(newValue, animated: true)
            navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(newValue, animated: true)
            toolBar.isHidden = newValue
            tabBar.isHidden = newValue
        }

        get {
            return _barsAreHidden
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        barsAreHidden = false
        dateLabel.text = nil
    }

    func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage? {
        barsAreHidden = true
        let screenShot = UIApplication.shared.screenShot
        barsAreHidden = false
        return screenShot
    }

    @IBAction func makeScreenShot(_ sender: Any) {
        dateLabel.text = "\(NSDate())"
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScreenShotDispalyViewController") as? ScreenShotDispalyViewController {
            vc.screenShotImage = generateMemedImage()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
        dateLabel.text = nil

    }

    @IBAction func hideAllBars(_ sender: Any) {
        barsAreHidden = true
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
            sleep(2)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.barsAreHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ScreenShotDispalyViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ScreenShotDispalyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var screenShotView: UIImageView!

    var screenShotImage: UIImage? 

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
        screenShotView.image = screenShotImage
    }

}
```

> Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11542" systemVersion="16B2555" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="QTa-p8-07R">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="11524"/>
        <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_40949933" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="zbR-st-Zkt">
                                <rect key="frame" x="-1" y="323" width="376" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <tabBar contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Dpj-QU-kbw">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="618" width="375" height="49"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <items>
                                    <tabBarItem systemItem="favorites" id="WkP-A3-0Vc"/>
                                    <tabBarItem systemItem="more" id="81b-9F-2KD"/>
                                </items>
                            </tabBar>
                            <toolbar opaque="NO" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0hT-0f-jdQ">
                                <rect key="frame" x="1" y="556" width="375" height="44"/>
                                <items>
                                    <barButtonItem title="Item" id="tfX-1b-ih3"/>
                                </items>
                            </toolbar>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="0hT-0f-jdQ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="-15" id="8N8-9Z-DX3"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Dpj-QU-kbw" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="wfy-db-euE" secondAttribute="top" id="9nc-Wr-VAM"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Dpj-QU-kbw" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leading" id="AiM-jN-NKi"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="zbR-st-Zkt" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Ga2-j4-QoN"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="zbR-st-Zkt" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Dpj-QU-kbw" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Jni-7E-zYV"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="zbR-st-Zkt" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Dpj-QU-kbw" secondAttribute="trailing" id="R6Q-JU-ezC"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Dpj-QU-kbw" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="0hT-0f-jdQ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="18" id="rO1-6C-bfo"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="zbR-st-Zkt" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerY" id="vlP-lE-CfP"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="0hT-0f-jdQ" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="-17" id="zCl-ym-Ozi"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="OWi-Si-dJ8">
                        <barButtonItem key="leftBarButtonItem" style="plain" id="NSu-0Y-F6Z">
                            <button key="customView" opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="t39-rx-C6w">
                                <rect key="frame" x="16" y="7" width="83" height="30"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="HideAll"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="hideAllBars:" destination="BYZ-38-t0r" eventType="touchUpInside" id="63T-fm-Ap3"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                        </barButtonItem>
                        <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem" title="ScreenShot" id="dQ2-9m-icX">
                            <button key="customView" opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="Yf7-f6-hlv">
                                <rect key="frame" x="276" y="7" width="83" height="30"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="ScreenShot"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="makeScreenShot:" destination="BYZ-38-t0r" eventType="touchUpInside" id="kx3-vG-GTt"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                        </barButtonItem>
                    </navigationItem>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="dateLabel" destination="zbR-st-Zkt" id="kpB-Cr-v6I"/>
                        <outlet property="tabBar" destination="Dpj-QU-kbw" id="YcD-Zr-zpm"/>
                        <outlet property="toolBar" destination="0hT-0f-jdQ" id="tdk-Xc-I7O"/>
                        <segue destination="ymc-dM-5SJ" kind="show" identifier="toScreenShotDispalyViewController" id="aJO-Nk-BGg"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1071.2" y="137.18140929535232"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Screen Shot Dispaly View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="W1a-69-l1F">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="ScreenShotDispalyViewController" useStoryboardIdentifierAsRestorationIdentifier="YES" id="ymc-dM-5SJ" customClass="ScreenShotDispalyViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_40949933" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="UPX-vz-TxQ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="SCl-Ty-ZAv"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Im2-Ro-q7m">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ZH8-h8-LKb">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="375" height="603"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="ZH8-h8-LKb" secondAttribute="trailing" id="2Lt-IE-fya"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZH8-h8-LKb" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Im2-Ro-q7m" secondAttribute="leading" id="E7b-gK-1Wy"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZH8-h8-LKb" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="UPX-vz-TxQ" secondAttribute="bottom" id="KhE-eL-Gia"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZH8-h8-LKb" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="SCl-Ty-ZAv" secondAttribute="top" id="rMk-ZS-1pf"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="screenShotView" destination="ZH8-h8-LKb" id="3Nd-Dr-Cbt"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="jkX-Yt-dtS" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1870" y="137"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="gon-W0-j8h">
            <objects>
                <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="QTa-p8-07R" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="gR4-pe-CNH">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="BYZ-38-t0r" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="sxR-Xd-KcW"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="03f-Oc-BF2" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="61.600000000000001" y="-545.57721139430294"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

### Result

[image]
[image]

### Details

xCode 8.1, swift 3

Comment: I added the tool bar and nav bar using storyboard.

Comment: Did you use tabBarViewController or you place tabBarView in your viewController?

Comment: Neither. I simply drag the toolbar to the storyboard, so its not a tabBarVC.